# Mongo DB - How to create a dynamic field based on the presence of element in array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a problem in Mongo for which I am not getting any clue to resolve it efficiently.

Say I have a 'Course' collection something like this (index is created on the 'studentIds' field):

```
{
    "courseId": 1,
    "name": "Mathematics",
    "studentIds": [1,3,5]
    ...
    ...
}
{
    "courseId": 2,
    "name": "Physics",
    "studentIds": [2,3,5]
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am trying to write a query which would return records in the below format:

Say student 1 is querying the courses, he is enrolled for courseId 1, so the 'enrolled' is true, but student 1 not enrolled for courseId 2 and so the 'enrolled' is false:

```
{
    "courseId": 1,
    "name": "Mathematics",
    "enrolled": true
}
{
    "courseId": 2,
    "name": "Physics",
    "enrolled": false
}
```

Only solution I can think of is have two queries, first query to find all course IDs the student is enrolled in and while running through the cursor on the courses in the second query, add 'enrolled' field based on the existence of the courseId in the result of the first query, but looking for a way to achieve this in a single query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```
let studentId = 1;
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            courseId: 1,
            name: 1,
            enrolled: { $in: [ studentId, "$studentIds" ] }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wy0kQOLp15o)

Comment: It worked exactly as expected, but couldn't find the $studentIds syntax anywhere in the docs link given or anywhere else in the docs. Could you please explain this part?

Comment: Dollar sign is used to define a field path in MongoDB https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-path-and-system-variables